# Dataframe containing all information for unique IDs based on presence/absence of another variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks somewhat as follows.

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  death = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
  other = letters[1:12])
```

I need to create a new data frame that includes all rows with the unique IDs for any ID that has had a death, much like this:

| ID | Death | Other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | a |
| 1 | 0 | b |
| 1 | 1 | c |
| 3 | 0 | g |
| 3 | 1 | h |
| 3 | 0 | i |

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but any time I try to subset by ID, I get error messages about length and not being able to subset with longer/shorter vectors. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove group from data.frame if at least one group member meets condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661704/remove-group-from-data-frame-if-at-least-one-group-member-meets-condition)

Comment: That's a good duplicate I think - it's worth noting that there's really no reason to do this as a group operation - it's just a single intersect/%in% operation: `data[data$id %in% data$id[data$death==1],]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` approach. It treats `id` as a group, and filter away any group that do not have `death > 0`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(any(death > 0))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id death other
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     0 a    
2     1     0 b    
3     1     1 c    
4     3     0 g    
5     3     1 h    
6     3     0 i
```

Answer (score 0):

As @thelatemail points out in the comments, this can be done in `base R` with:

```r
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), death = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0), other = letters[1:12])

data[data$id %in% data$id[data$death==1],]
#>   id death other
#> 1  1     0     a
#> 2  1     0     b
#> 3  1     1     c
#> 7  3     0     g
#> 8  3     1     h
#> 9  3     0     i
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>