# Remove group with identical values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

In the data below, I want to remove an `Utterance` if all the associated `f` values are the same. I've been using this but get an error:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  separate_rows(f, convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Utterance) %>%
  filter(if_all(f), ~. != lead(.))
```

Desired result:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  Utterance     f
  <chr>     <int>
1 B B C         2
2 B B C         2
3 B B C         3
7 A B C         1
8 A B C         2
9 A B C         3
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Utterance = c("B B C", "A A A", "A B C"),
  f = c("2,2,3", "1,1,1", "1,2,3")
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661704/remove-group-from-data-frame-if-at-least-one-group-member-meets-condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use `n_distinct` in `filter`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(f, convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Utterance) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(f) != 1)

# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   Utterance [2]
  Utterance     f
  <chr>     <int>
1 B B C         2
2 B B C         2
3 B B C         3
4 A B C         1
5 A B C         2
6 A B C         3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you were close. You need one value per group which can be achieved with the help of `all`/`any`.

`if_all`/`if_any` is useful when your data is in multiple columns. Here all the data that you want to compare is in single column i.e `f`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate_rows(f, convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Utterance) %>%
  filter(any(f != lead(f))) %>%
  ungroup

#  Utterance     f
#  <chr>     <int>
#1 B B C         2
#2 B B C         2
#3 B B C         3
#4 A B C         1
#5 A B C         2
#6 A B C         3
```